# How can i add native Splash Screen in Flutter app without using packages

Tags: android, flutter, dart, splash-screen, mobile-application

i have applications and i need to use splash screen with background color and app **icon** in center of it.

[image]

THE problem with **MIPMAP** , if i used image inside drawble directory it will work, but i need **mipmap** because it has multiple **dhp** sizes.

Anyone know solution of this?

**NOTE:** i know that the android 32 has special demonstration, i need solution that word in all version.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, to add a native splash screen without packages you need to prepare the app icons or the images you need with the following sizes

```
 1- mdpi = 1x pixel
 2-xhdpi = 2x pixel
 3-xxhdpi = 3x pixels
 4- xxxhdpi = 4x pixel
 5-hdpi = 1.5x pixels
 as x is the size of the ixcons
```

then add all the icons with the same name at path as each app icon at its positions like this images
[image: the places where you should put the images at]

the at android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml write the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/color_name" />

<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/image or app icon name" />
</item>
```

then to change the color

```
1-create colors file at 
 example_app/android/app/src/main/res/values/
 2- write the color code you want 

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

<color name="splash_color">#ED9728</color>

</resources>
```

[image: the color code example]

[image: change the splash screen color and icons example]

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best option, but If you want it to work in all versions and all devices, you can make your own splash screen page in flutter. And it can solve your problem.

For example in your main.dart file

```
 runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
          primary: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      home: SplashPage(), // here is your splash screen page
    ));
```

And in your SplashPage file, you can run some async functions if you want, and you can navigate to the main page after that.

Comment: I already do that mothod for my applications, but the problem is that is not native splash screan. i need android emplimentation to avoid the native white screen when the flutter app started, that's why i need to add the screen by XML

Comment: Author is asking about native splash screen not splash screen. There's a difference. Native splash is not handled by flutter runtime but native platform code

Answer (score 0):

Use [flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.17](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package to generate native splash screen for different platforms

Comment: my question is "How can i add native Splash Screen **without** using packages"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AdelMerioua Its easy use can use **appicon.co** here you just provide your app icon it will generate deferent resolutions for android as well as for IOS, and then you can replace it manually inside android and IOS.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: since you don't want to use a package, you can create the splash screen on your own by following the [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen).

<del>You can use [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) in your `dev_dependencies`.  That will make it available as a command line tool to generate the splash screen but the package will not be compiled into your app.  If you don't even want to keep it in your `dev_dependencies` you could run it once, remove it from your project, and then examine what files were chanced if you want to make additional manual tweaks.</del>

<del>Full disclosure: I maintain this package.</del>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is "How can i add native Splash Screen **without** using packages"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use a package?

Comment: because i wanna learn, at least for now.

Comment: A fine reply indeed